# Animate a view behind other views with Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I want to have a view animate behind all other views without affecting their layout (simply changing the background view's height and width). As far as I can tell you can't layer views in auto layout, so how does one go about this?

Comment: You certainly can layer views in Auto Layout; I've done it before.  What is not working?  Are the views above the one you are trying to animate transparent or translucent, so that you can see the one in the background?

Comment: Add some NSLayoutConstraint IBOutlets and change their .constant property to do a simple width/height change.

Comment: My problem is the layering. First, I am changing the .constant property as mentioned. Second, my view controller has to views in its root view, the first is a button which will stay fixed, the second is a progress indicator which takes up the whole screen (so it looks like the screen fills up from the bottom each time the button is tapped). When the progress indicator grows the first time, the the auto layout engine breaks. There are no constraints between the button and the progress indicator.